# Dynamic CSS class's attribute value from a JSTL set counter

Tags: html, css, jsp, jstl

I want retrieve the name of class I get from this code:

```
<c:set var="counter" value="0"/>
<c:forEach ...>
    <c:forEach ...>
       <c:set var="counter" value="${counter + 1}"/>
       <DIV class="div${counter}"> ... </DIV>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Is it possible to get the generated class name in the CSS code from this JSP page?

Comment: normally that would work, did you try it or not?

Comment: Yeah, it work but what I need to know is how to call the generated  DIV class in the CSS. Each generated div must have each own CSS class, So now I don't know how to generate those class dynamically in the CSS, you see?

Comment: if you want to give for each div a different CSS so what about usig tables ? then using **nth-child(N)** to give each row it's css [here example](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild), but if you want just to affecte one css to all divs then use  one ID outside the div but i don't think you look for doing it.